# I want to return only distinct latest of user id column (mysql/php)

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a register and login site where people can login and begin entering information into a form. I have a save progress button that inserts a new row with their user id stored in the second column into a table. I was wondering if there was a mysql query that could return only the newest distinct results User_Id? Like the greatest id of unique user_id?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use 'order by User_Id desc limit 1' in the select query. This will get you the latest unique User_Id.

Comment: Thanks! Now I wonder if you could help me figure out a query that would show a list of all latest entries? A list of all the latest save progresses of each person? like (3,bob, score 5) (4,sam, score 30) without showing duplicates of a user's past saves. The latest of each user.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like You are looking for [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

As fast as I understand, you need to insert a record and get it's id after the insert?

```
public $dbserver = '';
public $dbusername = '';
public $dbpassword = '';
public $dbname = '';

function openDb() {
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbserver . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $this->dbusername . '', '' . $this->dbpassword . '');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("error, please try again");
    }
    return $db;
}

function addNewUser($firstname) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO user (fname) VALUES(?)";
    $db = $this->openDb();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $db->lastInsertId('id');
}
```